# Alternative to text messaging

Tags: blackberry, sms, text-messaging, messaging

I have a BlackBerry issued to me by my employer.  Recently, in an effort to cut costs, the text messaging was turned off.  So there goes my social life :)

Anyway, looking for alternatives that provide text messaging on my BlackBerry.  Tried signing up for Google Voice but they are not taking on new users anymore.

In a nutshell, I want my text messaging back, even if it's a different number (like with Google Voice) or even if I have to pay for it.

As a bonus, I would love the ability to receive and respond to text messages on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's Gmail/GTalk to send SMS messages.  It isn't going to integrate into your phone as nicely as native SMS, but it will be retained in your chat history and you can use it from your computer.

Read the article [Really new in Labs this time: SMS Text Messaging for chat](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/12/really-new-in-labs-this-time-sms-text.html) on the Official Gmail Blog for further details.  One important thing to note from the article is that the person you send SMS messages to may incur fees, but you will not as long as your phone has a data plan.

Comment: That might not be a solution there - here is an excerpt from the link you provided: "Keep in mind that all these text messages count as part of your regular mobile messaging plan and might incur fees."

Comment: The BlackBerry client does not have the SMS capability and basically hands off that function to the BlackBerry's native capability.

Comment: You must not have read the article closely enough.  It says "on the receiving end" in reference to incurring fees.  Yes, *the person you send an SMS message to may incur fees*, but **you will not**.  You will be doing nothing more than using GTalk, which will no more incur fees than any other web browsing if you have a data plan.

Answer (score 0):

[TwitterBerry](http://orangatame.com/products/twitterberry/) if your organization's software policy allows it. Ditto with [Facebook client](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=2254487659)  for Blackberry.

Comment: I am looking for a point to point messaging, not me to the world messaging.

Comment: Twitter does direct messages

Answer (score 0):

As someone said, your favorite social site client might be a good replacement?

In general, my normal response is "use e-mail" - we've waited long enough in some western parts of the world to have e-mail as the natural and instant mobile message platform ^^

There should be lots of e-mail to SMS gateways to e-mail to as well if you really need to reach people with SMS.